# scraped items not being saved into database

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

my scrapy not saving data into database. please suggest.
it is scraping data,, but not adding those data into the database..
please look into the codes and sggest something,..

My spider.py file

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from project2spider.items import Project2Item
from scrapy.http import Request

class ProjectSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "project2spider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://directory.thesun.co.uk"]
    current_page_no = 1 
    start_urls = [ 
        "http://directory.thesun.co.uk/find/uk/computer-repair"
    ]   

    def get_next_url(self, fired_url):
        if '/page/' in fired_url:
            url, page_no = fired_url.rsplit('/page/', 1)
        else:
            if self.current_page_no != 1:
                #end of scroll
                return 
        self.current_page_no += 1
        return "http://directory.thesun.co.uk/find/uk/computer-repair/page/%s" % self.current_page_no

    def parse(self, response):
        fired_url = response.url
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="abTbl "]')
        for site in sites:
            item = Project2Item()
            item['Catogory'] = site.select('span[@class="icListBusType"]/text()').extract()
            item['Bussiness_name'] = site.select('a/@title').extract()
            item['Description'] = site.select('span[last()]/text()').extract()
            item['Number'] = site.select('span[@class="searchInfoLabel"]/span/@id').extract()
            item['Web_url'] = site.select('span[@class="searchInfoLabel"]/a/@href').extract()
            item['adress_name'] = site.select('span[@class="searchInfoLabel"]/span/text()').extract()
            item['Photo_name'] = site.select('img/@alt').extract()
            item['Photo_path'] = site.select('img/@src').extract()
            yield item
        next_url = self.get_next_url(fired_url)
        if next_url:
            yield Request(next_url, self.parse, dont_filter=True)
`
```

And my pipelines.py file::

```
from scrapy import log
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
import MySQLdb.cursors

# the required Pipeline settings.
class MySQLStorePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        #  db settings
        self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb',
                db='project2',
                user='root',
                passwd='',
                host='127.0.0.1',
                port='3306',                            
                cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
                charset='utf8',
                use_unicode=True
            )

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    # run db query in thread pool
    query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item)
    query.addErrback(self.handle_error)
    return item


def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
    #runs the condition 
    insert_id = tx.execute(\
        "insert into crawlerapp_directory (Catogory, Bussiness_name, Description, Number, Web_url) "
        "values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
        (item['Catogory'][0],
         item['Bussiness_name'][0],
         item['Description'][0],
         item['Number'][0],
         item['Web_url'][0],
         )
        )
    #connection to the foreign key Adress.
    tx.execute(\
        "insert into crawlerapp_adress (directory_id, adress_name) "
        "values (%s, %s)",
        (insert_id,
         item['adress_name'][0]
         )
        )
    #connection to the foreign key Photos.
    tx.execute(\
        "insert into crawlerapp_photos (directory_id, Photo_path, Photo_name) "
        "values (%s, %s, %s)",
        (insert_id,
         item['Photo_path'][0],
         item['Photo_name'][0]
         )
        )
    log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
def handle_error(self, e):
    log.err(e)
```

I am not being able to save data into my database
please help

Comment: You keep posting the same problem expecting people to review all of your code.  Figure out where the database write fails, hypothesize what is causing the problem, test your hypothesis, then post a specific question to SO that shows what you've done and the code that is the source of the problem.

Comment: But sir I have made changes in my spider...And still its not working ..I really need help..cause I need to show this project tomorrow..and I am just left with 7 hrs more..please help..

Comment: And I just need help in saving data into my DB ..and nothing else..
all the other parts are ready sir..

Comment: I am trying to help by explaining how SO works.  If you isolate the problem before asking for help, you can get an answer in minutes.  If you keep posting huge chunks of code just asking people to figure out why it doesn't work, people will mostly ignore you.  It see you have a line that says, `log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)`.  Does that ever get called?

Comment: I kept that line to make me aware that the items scraped are inserted into the database. But neither the cmd returns that line, nor any data is being stored into the database... :(